# Subplot and legend each graph in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, legend, subplot

I am trying to write a matlab script using for loop and I want to make a 4*2 subplot.

I tried to use the `legend` function into each graph but, I faced a problem. I intend that each graph has as legend using `legend('Motor1+i')`, but all graphs have same name `Motor1+i`.

I want to have `Motor1`, `Motor2`, `Motor3`, ...

```
g_wPWMOut=[g_wPWMOut0 g_wPWMOut1 g_wPWMOut2 g_wPWMOut3 g_wPWMOut4 ...
              g_wPWMOut5 g_wPWMOut6 g_wPWMOut7];

figure
for i=0:1:7;
   subplot(421+i)
   plot(FCCTime, g_wPWMOut(:,(1+i)))
   grid on
   legend('Motor1+i')
   ymax = max(g_wPWMOut(:,(1+i)));
   ymin = min(g_wPWMOut(:,(1+i)));
   xmax = max(FCCTime);
   xmin = min(FCCTime);
   axis([xmin-((xmax-xmin)*0.05) xmax+((xmax-xmin)*0.05) ...
   ymin-((ymax-ymin)*0.05) ymax+((ymax-ymin)*0.05)])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but try:

```
mylegend = 'Motor';
mylegend = [mylegend num2str(i)];
legend(mylegend);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to warn you that using `i` as variable is not advised since it's used as the complex imaginary unit. Use `ii` for example.

Then, you misunderstood the usage of `subplot`. You give `421+i` as argument, but in your case, it needs 3 arguments. You should have given `4,2,1+i`

Finally, you can use [`num2str`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), to convert `ii` to a string, combined with [`strcat`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to create a new string with `Motor` and `ii`.

```
for ii = 0:7
    subplot(4,2,1+ii);
    plot(FCCTime, g_wPWMOut(:,(1+ii)))
    legend(strcat('Motor', num2str(1+ii)))
end
```

And you'll have a result like:

[image: legend]